# Identify whether a function is inlined in the LLVM IR

Tags: llvm

We are instrumenting the source code at compile-time, based on the LLVM IR. In this procedure, we want to skip the functions that are already inlined (e.g., due to compile-time optimization).

How can we determine whether a function has been inlined in our LLVM pass?

Comment: I don't think your question is specific enough to be answerable. Do you have some function foo() and want to know if it has had bar() inlined into it? Or are you interested in seeing if bar() is inlinable or had an `inline`-like attribute in the source code?

Answer (score 1):

This seems rather vague and open to many interpretations...

One way to see whether `foo()` is inlined into `bar()` is to loop over the instructions in `bar()` and see whether any of them are `call %foo` or similar. If that is the case, then at least one call wasn't inlined, even if other calls may have been.

Another way is to look at the debug info. Suppose that `foo()` originates in foo.c lines 10 to 20. You can look at the debug info for all instructions in `bar()` and check whether any refer to lines 10-20 of foo.c. If any do, then at least one call was inlined, even if others were not.

I can think of at least two more ways, too, and I'm sure there are more. (Edit: I can think of three, including one quite nice way: Attach some unique metadata to the instructions in `foo()` early in the compilation and see where that metadata is found just before native codegen.)

Comment: Thanks. However, indirect calls may cause the function to have no direct caller, but it is not inlined. We checked the metadata in ``.ll`` file but found nothing related to function inline.

Comment: Anyone can define and add metadata, including you.

Comment: Another point — if the call relationship cannot be detected by your analysis, then it also cannot be detected by the inliner's analysis, so in those cases the call is certainly not inlined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we gradually noticed that the "inline" operation is in terms of the specific call site rather than the callee function. Thus, one function may not have an attribute of "inline". For each function, it may be inlined at some call points but called normally at other call points, so we shouldn't skip them in our instrument pass.